# Find matching nodes, update if exists otherwise append to root XML

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I am trying to find the best most efficient way of iterating through a parent xml, trying to find a match from a passed through child xml. If an exact match is found, I need to update the matching xml node in the parent xml, or append the new child xml into the parent xml.

```
    --There are 2 AttributeBalance Nodes, each having 3 Attribute Nodes.
    DECLARE @ParentFromTableXML XML

    SET @ParentFromTableXML = '
    <AttributeGroup>
    <GroupID>2009</GroupID>
    <GroupCode>Clothing</GroupCode>
    <GroupDescription>Clothing</GroupDescription>
    <AttributeBalanceGroup>
        <CreditTotal>935</CreditTotal>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>93</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1015</ValueID>
                <Value>S</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1029</ValueID>
                <Value>Black</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>78</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1015</ValueID>
                <Value>S</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1030</ValueID>
                <Value>Red</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
    </AttributeBalanceGroup>
</AttributeGroup>'

    /* This has 2 AttributeBalance Nodes, each having 3 Attribute Nodes. 1 Attribute Node exists in the @ParentFromTableXML while one does not. The one which does not, i need to append to the @ParentFromTableXML */

    DECLARE @ChildParamXML XML

        SET @ChildParamXML = '
        <AttributeGroup>
    <GroupID>2009</GroupID>
    <GroupCode>Clothing</GroupCode>
    <GroupDescription>Clothing</GroupDescription>
    <AttributeBalanceGroup>
        <CreditTotal>935</CreditTotal>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>12</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1015</ValueID>
                <Value>S</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1029</ValueID>
                <Value>Black</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>65</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1017</ValueID>
                <Value>XXXL</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1029</ValueID>
                <Value>Black</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
    </AttributeBalanceGroup>
</AttributeGroup>'
```

I thought of trying to use a FLWOR statement, something like this

```
SELECT @ParentFromTableXML.query('
    for $Attrib in /AttributeGroup/AttributeBalanceGroup/AttributeBalance/Attribute         
    return
        for $PassedAttrib in //@ChildParamXML
        return
          if (data($Attrib/TypeID) = data($PassedAttrib)) then
            --Need to return the current node, so i can add the ChildParamXML "Credit" 
            <Result>equal</Result>       
          else
            <Result>Not-equal</Result>           

               ') AS Result
```

I also thought of using a node comparison operator "is", something like this

```
SELECT @ParentFromTableXML.query('       
    if ( (//AttributeGroup/AttributeBalanceGroup/AttributeBalance/Attribute)[1]       
          is        
          (//@ChildParamXML)[1] )        
    then       
          --Need to return the current node, so i can add the ChildParamXML "Credit" to the ParentFromTableXML "Credit"
          <Result>equal</Result>       
    else       
          <Result>Not-equal</Result>       
         ') as Result
```

Once I have found a match, I wish to return the XML node and use the .modify() command to update the @ParentFromTableXML "Credit" amount by adding the @ChildParamXML "Credit" amount. This must only occur on the exact match node, per node.

```
DECLARE @sumCredit DECIMAL

SET @sumCredit = (/*Found Parent XML Node*/ + /*Found Child XML Node*/)
@ParentFromTableXML.modify('replace value of (/ResultXML/Credit/text())[1]

  (sql:variable("@sumCredit")')
```

If no match is found in the entire @ParentFromTableXML, i need to append the @ChildParamXML to the existing @ParentFromTableXML.

So my end result should be

```
-- This XML would be the end result, with 11 AttributeBalance Items since one was appended and 3 which were updated

    DECLARE @EndResultXML XML

    SET @EndResultXML = '
    <AttributeGroup>
    <GroupID>2009</GroupID>
    <GroupCode>Clothing</GroupCode>
    <GroupDescription>Clothing</GroupDescription>
    <AttributeBalanceGroup>
        <CreditTotal>248</CreditTotal>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>105</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1015</ValueID>
                <Value>S</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1029</ValueID>
                <Value>Black</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>78</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1015</ValueID>
                <Value>S</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1030</ValueID>
                <Value>Red</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
        <AttributeBalance>
            <Credit>65</Credit>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1013</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Size</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1020</ValueID>
                <Value>XXXL</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <TypeID>1018</TypeID>
                <TypeName>Color</TypeName>
                <ValueID>1029</ValueID>
                <Value>Black</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeBalance>
    </AttributeBalanceGroup>
</AttributeGroup>
'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you trim the example data down to just the bare minimum needed to reproduce it please?

Comment: XML functionality in SQL Server varies greatly from version to version. Which one you use?

Comment: I need it to work from SQL Server 2008 R2 upwards.

Comment: I have shorted the example data as per your requests

Comment: I am struggling to find a question here (already indicated by the lack of a question mark anywhere). What exactly is your problem here, at which point does something not work? You also propose two solutions here (using flwor and is), but don't mention anything with them being wrong.